# how to change size of subsection and subsubsection title

Tags: sectioning, fontsize

In my project, I want to change fontsize for the subsection and subbsection (include their number) to the same size as what I write in the next line of its (I don't know how to say this in English naturally). How can I do it ? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[13pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}


\usepackage{sectsty}

% for the chapter
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\newlength\mylength
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\large{\hspace{0.04cm}}}
\settowidth\mylength{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}

% for the section
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{2em}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{17}{20}\selectfont}

% for the subsection
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\hspace{-.45cm} }

% for the subsubsection
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}\hspace{-.45cm} }

\begin{document}
\large{
\chapter{Knowledge}
\section{Algebra}


\subsection{Matrix.}
\subsection*{\Large{1.1.1. Matrix.} }


\subsubsection{Definition.}
\subsection*{1.1.1.1. Definition.}


}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Addings dots/periods/full stops after the sectioning number is also an objective? Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico yes it's right

Comment: @bonk not so much indeed, I tried applying the code which is demonstrated in this link but it was not compatible to my original project

Comment: Off-topic: `\large` is a switch and doesn't take an argument. If you want to limit the scope of `\large`, you need to write `{\large ...}`, *not* `\large{...}`.

Comment: @Mico I wIll notes that. How about the size of the subsection and subsubsection ?

Comment: "it was not compatible to my original project" What issues were you getting with the linked answer's code? Are you getting errors, or does it not do what you want? I see that you're already using the `sectsty` package, does the `sectsty` example in that answer not work?

Comment: @bonk [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/bmjsqbwmcjxs#af5334) is what happened when I applied the code in that link

Comment: It looks like it worked as intended. It didn't do *exactly* what you wanted because that linked question's author isn't trying to do exactly what you want to do. You'll need to read the code, understand what it does, and change it to make it work for your purpose.

Comment: Also, the linked answer provided *multiple* solutions. One of them uses `sectsty`, which you're already using in your example. Why not just use that solution? I had tested it out myself already and it definitely does work.

Comment: @bonk I have another question, do you know why my code for the subsubsection didn't ouput the section number for the subsubsection ? I don't understand why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150763/discussion-between-bonk-and-permqi).